# Why is Apache failing to restart? "review the situation by hand"

Tags: apache2, 13.10, restart

```
ubuntu@fast:~$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
 * There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your 
   pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, 
   Please review the situation by hand.
```

What is going on?

```
cat /var/run/apache2.pid 
1342

pidof apache2
1723 1468 1467 1466 1440 1439 1438 1433 1348 1347 1342
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of the following commands, by running it in terminal:  `cat /var/run/apache2.pid` and `pidof apache2` .

Answer (score 1):

Check if pid file path set in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` equals `APACHE_PID_FILE` variable exported in `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Answer (score 1):

Check pid of Apache2 by executing:

```
pidof apache2
```

Then kill the shown pid be executing:

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

Restart Apache2.

Comment: not working for me. the process is still running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to reply for this question but it might help someone in future.

> 1. execute : **`pidof apache2`**
> 2. Then, `sudo kill -9 pid`
> 3. kill all **pid** by executing above command
> 4. Start apache : `sudo service apache2 start`

Done.