# How to restart apache2 when I get a pid conflict?

Tags: server, apache2

I receive the same message than explained [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330047/why-is-apache-failing-to-restart-review-the-situation-by-hand/431920) when I'm trying to restart apache2 :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2 [fail]
 * There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand.
```

But the problem is that I don't have any file inside /var/run/apache2.
The command pidof apache2 returns :

```
1274
```

I don't know if it will help but here is the line in apache2.conf :

```
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
```

And the one in envvars :

```
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
```

Should I manually create a .pid file inside /var/run/apache2 ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: How was Apache installed? LAMP, nginx, XAMPP? Upstart may not know how to handle the instance you installed if they are still invoking scripts in init.d

Comment: I installed Apache via sudo apt-get install on Ubuntu 13.10 (on an Azure virtual machine). Do I need to type a specific command to know the invoking scripts ?

Comment: `sudo kill -9 1274` then try `service apache2 status`  If it comes back with `stopped/waiting` then `sudo service apache2 start`

Comment: Wow it worked perfectely ! I feel dumb not to have tried that before... Thank you very much @douggro !

Comment: @douggro You should enter `sudo kill -9 <pid>` as an answer. It worked for me too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to @douggro who found the answer.

Find the processus id of Apache2 with :

```
pidof apache2
```

Kill the process(es) :

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

Then you can start Apache2 as usually :

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

**UPDATE**

If `sudo kill -9 <pid>` doesn't work, just try `sudo kill <pid>` !

Comment: You might [edit] your answer to include the details and make it more useful. Comments aren't meant to store lasting information.

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

After trying various one liners that did not work I found this

```
kill -9 $(pidof apache2)
```

that seems to work just fine